# Appium - Close one iOS application and reopen another application

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have the following scenario to be automated. How this could be achieved through Appium.

```
1. Launch my application register a user with an gmail id.
2. Close the application.
3. Launch Safari browser and navigate to gmail login
4. Click on the registration link.
```

Here, challenging part is point number 2 and 3.
Can Appium session be disconnected?
Can Appium start a new session for a pre installed application like Safari?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the same appium server instance. No need to kill the server, but you will want to probably use two different driver instances.

```
  AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    IOSDriver iosDriver;

        public void setUp() throws IOException {
            service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
            service.start();
        }    

        public void startMyApplication(){
            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "3838n838fn38jf8n838ffabcdefg");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.IOS);
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "com.your_package.name");

            iosDriver = new IOSDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", dc);
        }

        public void testMyGoogleLoginOnMyApplication(){
          //I intend to do something here
          //Once i am finished, I close my application
          iosDriver.quit();
        }

        public void startSafari(){
            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "3838n838fn38jf8n838ffabcdefg");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.IOS);
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "com.safari_package.name");

            iosDriver = new IOSDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", dc);
        }

        public void testSafari(){
          //I intend to go to google and do stuff
          //Once i am finished, I close my application
          iosDriver.quit();
        }

        public void finished(){
            service.stop();
        }
```

Comment: I will try this. How to get the package name for applications like safari,gmail etc.?

Comment: Here is a tool. https://help.tune.com/marketing-console/finding-ios-app-details/#bundle-lookup

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a solution that works for all iOS versions and Xcode versions:

driver.background_app(-1) 
From the springboard, find the Icon and click it!